# Using Liferay for an already developed project

Tags: liferay

First of all, let me tell you what I am or my company is intended to do. We have already developed a project using Java, JSP and Servlet. We want it to integrate with Liferay so that we can change logo, css, images, themes or any other UI related component at run time using Liferay admin panel. But backend should be what we have developed.

In short, the UI of our project is controlled by Liferay, but control of data displayed on UI or submitted from UI should be from our developed backend code.

Now I have a few questions regarding above said approach of fulfilling the requirement:

1. What we are trying to do is possible?
2. Is this approach recommendable for what we intended to do?
3. Or do we need to develop our project from scratch to fit into Liferay? Like developing portlets and deploying in Liferay or other approach that has been given in Liferay documentation.
4. What about database integration? We have around 15 columns/fields in user table in database of our project which is completely different from that of Liferay's user table.

Liferay is a very new for us. We have checked the documentation section of Liferay but still few things like above said requirements and its implementation is not clear. Also, we would like to know in what scenarios/requirements Liferay is useful.

Comment: I'm not sure you are posting your question in the right place. It's a very wide question.

Comment: Please suggest where should I post my question so that I could get the answers to my question. I have already posted same thing on Liferay forum(http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/17560580) but no reply yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok let me try to answer your question point-wise and I would answer your last question first, which should automatically clear other questions:

> Q. Also, we would like to know in what scenarios/requirements Liferay is useful.

This can have a very wide answer, but I have made it shorter for you:

1. If your site is content heavy and not data heavy then go for Portal
2. If you plan to use only a single web-application in a portal then I would suggest standalone custom developed web-application is much better.

I agree liferay portal will give you lot of things out-of-box like Single Sign-on, authorization, authentication, friendly-url and page creation and also lot of applications like Blogs, Wikis, Document library, some social networking apps etc. But think about it, do you really need all this? if not, then this is overkill

Here are some really nice links to better understand a portal's usage:

1. [When to use a portal](http://blogs.perficient.com/portals/2012/01/06/when-to-use-a-portal-2/)
2. [Why to use portal technology](http://www.coderanch.com/t/203709/Portals-Portlets/java/Why-Portal)
3. [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) tag wiki: It has nice description as to what is liferay and it also contains relevant links to Admin guide which will tell you what all functionalities liferay has and how you can manage it.

So still if you find your other questions unanswered, read-on ...

> Q1. What we are trying to do is possible?

Nope. Portlet technology is different from Servlet technology. Liferay (or anyother portal) does not provide a way (atleast a simple one) to integrate servlets that would render pages inside a portal. For eg: Since with servlet you define URL mappings for a particular servlets before-hand in a web.xml but in a portal the URLs are generated by the Portlet Container. So portals work with portlets and not Servlets.

> Q2. Is this approach recommendable for what we intended to do?

Nope. As I already explained in Q1.

> Q3. Or do we need to develop our project from scratch to fit into Liferay? Like developing portlets and deploying in Liferay or other approach that has been given in Liferay documentation.

If you want to go the liferay way then Yes.
If you want to build applications that talk to your custom tables then portlets are the way to go.

> Q4. What about database integration? We have around 15 columns/fields in user table in database of our project which is completely different from that of Liferay's user table.

If you go with Liferay. In this scenario you can create a combination of `liferay-hook` & `portlet` (may be using `service-builder`) to customize liferay's User creation mechanism and there by store data in both Liferay's User table and your custom tables.
Liferay's permission system is really fine-grained so you can also benefit from this system and put permission even on the data level.

**In conclusion I would say:**
Everything boils down to what your requirements are and what resources you have. And sometimes what future requirements you can have.

<sub>**Note:** All the terms used in this answer which are specific to liferay (like service-builder, hook etc) are explained in the [liferay](/questions/tagged/liferay) tag wiki.</sub>

Hope this helps. If you would like to know anything specific I would gladly update my answer.